# REGEX: How to search and replace a character in the first half of a string

Tags: regex

I am using an app called Transnomino (on Mac) to rename some multimedia files using regular expression pattern matching.

I need a regex expression that will replace all "." (periods) in a string up until it hits the following sub-string `- S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9] -`. To be clear it should stop after the sub-string, it should not replace any periods after that point.

Note I know there are ways in other languages e.g. Python, Perl, PHP etc.. But just regular expressions please.

Obviously the regex s/./ /g would replace all the periods in the name with spaces, but I need it to stop when it gets too S01E01.
The regex I'm using to clean up the file names is below, but I've had no luck making something that stops at a substring.

This handles capitalisation of the S and E, and it inserts " - " as a break.
`s/(^.*[a-zA-Z0-9])[\s\.][Ss]([0-9][0-9])[Ee]([0-9][0-9])[\s\.]/$1 - S$2E$3 - /g`

For example

- `My.name.is.bob - S01E01 - Pilot.mp4` ==> `My name is bob - S01E01 - Pilot.mp4`
- `My.name.is.bob - S01E13 - The finale...mkv` ==> `My name is bob - S01E13 - The finale...mkv`
- `Great.times.outdoors - S11E21.mp4` ==> `Great times outdoors - S11E21.mp4`

Comment: Does the app support capture groups? If so then `$1` of something like `[^\.]*(\.)*[^\.]* - S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9] - .*` should fit the bill.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yes it does support capture groups, the app uses the ICU implementation of regular expressions (http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp).  I can't get your regex to work, if I'm reading it correctly you are putting the period into the capture group, instead of the surrounding text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want with a positive look-ahead assertion:

```
s/\.(?=.*S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9] -)/ /g
```

This will replace all dots that are eventually followed by your stop pattern, but no others.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dHp6js/3)

Caveat: if your stop pattern occurs more than once, all dots preceding the last occurrence will be replaced.

Comment: That is perfect thank you very much for your help and clear answer